# Show Date in a TextView

Tags: android, string, date, textview

Hello I Want to show the actual date in a Text-view but I have some problems.
I receive the date correctly and I print it on the log and I see it. I save the date in a String but when I try to pass the String to the text returns a nullpointerexception and I don't know why because I print the string on the log and I see it. 
My code:

```
public void ComprobarDia() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    Datos.fecha=formattedDate;
    Log.d("Calendario", Datos.fecha);
    TV.setText(Datos.fecha);
}
```

I execute it in the OnCreate method. The "Datos.fecha" is a public static String.
Why I receive the nullpointerexception in the last line but in the log it shows correctly?

Comment: My guess is `TV` is `null`

Comment: How is `TV` defined? Did you double check the ID in your layout? Take care that you already assigned your layout in `onCreate()` using `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)`.

Comment: Lots of ifs and buts @Guixe94. Post your `onCreate()` to clear all doubts. And better if you post your error stack

Comment: Thanks it was not defined correctly.  I put this: TV=(TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.TV); on the OnCreateView (because I have it on a fragment) and now i don't have the nullpointer error but the text of the textView does not show the date.. stays in white, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your `TextView`, hence it's `null`.

Your `onCreate()` method needs to include this code.

```
//Layout with your TextView
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
```

Then, you can call

```
TV.setText(Datos.fecha);
```

Comment: How do you know for sure that he has not initialized `TV`?

Comment: Because `TV.setText(Datos.fecha);` is giving a `nullPointerException`, as stated in the question. @EdmDroid

Comment: Yes, I put this: TV=(TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.TV); on the OnCreateView (because I have it on a fragment) and now i don't have the nullpointer error but the text of the textView does not show the date.. stays in white, anyone knows why?

Comment: Because the person asking said it happens in the last line, and Datos cannot be null, otherwise it would have caused an exception earlier. Thus TV must be null.

Comment: @Guixe94 I'm not sure. It's hard to tell without more code. I suggest you open a new question, and try to be as specific as possible. Show more relevant code, and try to hint where you think it might go wrong.

Comment: How about the theme of the Activity, light or black, and the color of textview? I think you should try to debug step by step carefully before asking.